# android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{43039af8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192}

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am opening a custom dialog on the "click on forgot password" button. In custom dialog click on send button, I'm retrieving password but I got this exception. Here is my code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;

    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN:
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


            dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
            dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
            break;
    }
    return dialogDetails;

}

@Override
@Deprecated
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_LOGIN:
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
        Button loginbutton = (Button) alertDialog
           .findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        Button cancelbutton = (Button) alertDialog
           .findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
      final EditText  emailid = (EditText) alertDialog
           .findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_name);

      loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new ForgotPassword().execute();

        }
    });

      cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


        break;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
class ForgotPassword extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    // Required initialization

    private final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PtLogin.this);
    String data = "";
    EditText etuser_Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_name);




    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        dialog.show();

    }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {



        //http://69.73.184.155/~isoft/doctorApp/web_serv/


        //forget_pass.php?access_token=testermanishrahul234142test&userName=%@
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token","testermanishrahul234142test"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName",etuser_Name.getText().toString()));



        Content=new ServiceHandler().makeServiceCall(AppConstant.FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL, 2, nameValuePairs);
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // Close progress dialog
    dialog.dismiss();







        /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

        String OutputData = "";
        JSONObject jsonResponse;

        try {

            /******
             * Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the
             * JSON string.
             ********/
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

            System.out.println("=====response" + jsonResponse.toString());

            /*****
             * Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a
             * JSONArray.
             ***/
            /******* Returns null otherwise. *******/
            JSONObject jsonMainNode = jsonResponse
                    .getJSONObject("document");

            JSONObject response = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject("response");

            String status = response.getString("status");
            if (status != null && status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

            }
            String message = response.getString("message");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "" + status + ":" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
```

..........my logcat is here............

```
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.doctorpocket.PtLogin has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42e815e0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:425)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:250)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:297)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at com.example.doctorpocket.PtLogin$ForgotPassword.onPreExecute(PtLogin.java:359)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at com.example.doctorpocket.PtLogin$1.onClick(PtLogin.java:317)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
04-01 12:30:02.601: E/WindowManager(30294):     at `enter code here`dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your activity into AlertDialog.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PtLogin.this);
```